# efficient querying of array property in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I've wanting to query for nodes that have a specific value in a string array property. For instance my nodes might have 2 properties, name (a string) and aliases (a string array). I have created an index on both properties using something like `CREATE INDEX ON :F2(name)`.
I can query the name property using something cypher like this, and the result is immediate:

```
MATCH (p:F2) WHERE p.name = 'john' RETURN p;
```

I can query the aliases property using cypher like this, and I get the expected result but the response is very slow:

```
MATCH (p:F2) WHERE ANY(item IN p.aliases WHERE item = 'big john') RETURN p;
```

This looks like either the query is not optimal or the index is not being used.
Can someone suggest how to do this correctly. I'm pretty new to neo4j and cyper :-(

Answer (score 1):

You could refactor your graph to make alias a node. So that any `F2` node has zero or more aliases.

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Alias(name)
```

Then you could query it with something like this...

```
MATCH (p:F2)-[:HAS_ALIAS]->(:Alias {name: 'big john'})
RETURN p
```

Comment: That might be a good way to go if/when this expands in scope, but right now I'm preferring something that's light weight and minimises memory footprint, so would like to be able to do this by querying on properties.

Comment: @tdudgeon The index on an array is actually on the hash of the array, not the individual elements. The best you can do with arrays is to scan through every array of every node. Faster queries require more memory. (Indexes create extra data to make queries faster) So you really can't have the best of both worlds.

Comment: OK, that makes array properties much less useful.

Comment: @tdudgeon the need of querying an array is already telling you that your model is wrong and that you need to extract those arrays as nodes and relationships. Memory footprint is really not relevant here, it is actually more memory consuming to check property values rather than index lookups and chasing pointers.